# React - textarea at nested arrow component - unable to call set state on value changed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to call the parent component to set the state.

When typing in the input at the inner component, it lose the focus.

Example:

```
const X = () => {
  const Y = (props) => <textarea onChange={(e)=>{props._s(e.target.value)}}/>
  const [comments, setComments] = useState("");
  return (
    <div>
      <Y _s={setComments}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Is there a problem to declare an arrow function component in a component?

Regards

Comment: That setup is rather confusing. Would you kindly update the code snippet to clearly show the parent/child component relationship?

Comment: Possibly: If the component is mapped, this would typically happen if the key attribute value changes between renders, or is completely left off the component during the mapping.

Comment: The reason here is because everytime this component rerenders, const Y is recreated and it loses its state

Comment: I tried also pass the 'comment' to Y and set as it as the value of the textarea but it didnt help

Comment: did you manage?

Comment: I saw that the [docs](nested functions) said that I can't call the hooks from the nested functions. Wrapping the call to the hooks with a function didn't help so I had to move it out of the declaration of the parent component. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try declare Y outside of the component so it is not recreated every render

```
const Y = (props) => <textarea onChange={(e)=>{props._s(e.target.value)}}/>

const X = () => {  
  const [comments, setComments] = useState("");
  return (
    <div>
      <Y _s={setComments}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```